# Why can't I see these objects or use Texture Painting on them?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I'm new to Blender and hitting a wall here.  So I created a UV map for the eyes of this character which I've been able to view, but I can't figure out how to start texturing the eyes.  It just won't let me view the eyes in texture painting at all (can't even choose texture painting), and now I can't see the UV Map anymore.  I would be fine with creating the texture externally in photoshop, but I'm at a loss here.  I followed a tutorial to paint the character, but not sure where I'm going wrong with the eyes here.

[image]

Dropbox files here (Please let me know if the link or files don't work): https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m7whjq6qsbgr7w5/AAAMgOmrx6AqFT5hHSwzL7Jta?dl=0

Comment: Also note that UV map will be only shown in Edit or Texture paint mode

Answer (score 2):

Press numpad /  to exit Local View and you will see the mesh objects